# Nodejs: Export the whole object VS export API only

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know which is the common way in Node.js to use `module.exports=` in Node.js files. Here is two way to export a object named `printer`:

Way 1: export the while object, including the internal function

```
const printer = {
    loadInk: function () {
        console.log('this is a internal function that should be called by printer itself only')
    },
    print: function () {
        console.log('this is a api function ')
    }
}

module.exports = printer
```

Way 2: only export the api function as a new object

```
function loadInk() {
    console.log('this is a internal function that should be called by printer itself only')
}
function print() {
    console.log('this is a api function ')
}

module.exports = {
    print: print
}
```

As a Java-backgroud programmer, I think way 2 is  better because it hide the internal details. Am I right, or am I missing something here? Please help.

Comment: Export the abstraction, the API. Why export more than you need? Hide the details. Btw, could could export the object like `module.exports = {print}` and it'll work like the latter.

Comment: Way 2's better. You can also write like module.exports.print = print